# Problem related to Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem**
Let $f:B(0,1) \to B(0,1)$ be a holomorphic function. Prove that if there are two distinct points $z_1,z_2$ such that $f(z_1)=z_1$ and $f(z_2)=z_2$, then $f(z)=z$ for all $z \in B(0,1)$. (Consider the function $g(z)=\dfrac{h(z)-z_1}{1-\overline{z_1}h(z)}$, with $h(z)=f(\dfrac{z+z_1}{1+\overline{z_1}z})$ and use Schwarz lemma.)

**Sketch of solution**

I've proved that if $|\alpha| \neq 1$, the function $\gamma(z)=\dfrac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$ sends $\alpha$ to $0$ and the circle $\{|z|=1\}$ to itself, and that ${\gamma}^{-1}=\dfrac{z+\alpha}{1+\overline{\alpha}z}$. Now, suppose I could prove that $\gamma$ sends $B(0,1)$ to itself, then:

If we take $\alpha=z_1$ (if $z_1=0$, then consider $\alpha=z_2$), the function $g(z)$ is $g(z)=\gamma \circ f \circ {\gamma}^{-1}(z)$. So $g(0)=\gamma \circ f \circ {\gamma}^{-1}(0)=\gamma \circ f (z_1)=\gamma(z_1)=0$.

As $\gamma$ is a bijection, we have $\gamma(z_2) \neq 0$. But then $g(\gamma(z_2))=\gamma \circ f \circ {\gamma}^{-1}(g(z_2))=\gamma \circ f(z_2)=\gamma(z_2)$.

By the Schwarz lemma, $g(z)=az$ for some $a : |a|=1$. Since $g(\gamma(z_2))=\gamma(z_2)$ and $\gamma(z_2) \neq 0$, it must be $a=1$. This means $\gamma \circ f \circ {\gamma}^{-1}(z)=Id(z)$, so $f(z)={\gamma}^{-1} \circ Id \circ \gamma (z)=Id(z)=z$

I would appreciate if someone could help me to prove that $\gamma(B(0,1))=B(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute

$$\lvert 1-\overline{\alpha}z\rvert^2 - \lvert z-\alpha\rvert^2 = (1 - \overline{\alpha}z - \alpha\overline{z} + \lvert\overline{\alpha}z\rvert^2) - (\lvert z\rvert^2 - \overline{\alpha}z - \alpha\overline{z} + \lvert\alpha\rvert^2) = (1-\lvert z\rvert^2)(1-\lvert \alpha\rvert^2)$$

to conclude that $\gamma$ is an automorphism of the unit disk if and only if $\lvert\alpha\rvert < 1$.